# How to get value from a dynamically created JTable

Tags: java, swing, variables, jtable

I am new to JTable. I have created a JTable dynamically and I don't know how to get data from that dynamic JTable.

The JTable is created in an anonymous class inside a MouseListener, inside an anonymous class. I am unable to access the JTable outside the anonymous class.

Comment: you'll need a reference to that table _outside_ of the listener. Anyway, better not re-create a table each time the data is changed, instead update its model. Please be sure to read and understand the relevant chapters in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag

Comment: "The problem is the JTable is created inside a MouseListener,inside an anonymous class." Stop doing that and there's no problem... If you declare it as a member of the class which contains the MouseListener, the MouseListener will still have access to it.

Answer (score 3):

The data resides in the TableModel; to obtain this, you call [getModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29).
Then you use [getValueAt(int,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) to get the value of a specific cell.

You say you only have access to the JTable inside an anonymous class.
So the scope of the JTable is that anonymous class. Instead of declaring the JTable inside the anonymous class, you should make the JTable a field of the enclosing class. Then you have access to it.

Comment: The problem is the JTable is created inside a MouseListener,inside an anonymous class. The rows will be varied depends on the user entry of rows required. I am unable to access the JTable outside the anonymous class.

Comment: I have edited your question to reflect this. On [SO], we can do that - but it's best if you do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

[table.getValueAt(row, column);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: The problem is the JTable is created inside a MouseListener,inside an anonymous class. The rows will be varied depends on the user entry of rows required. I am unable to access the JTable outside the anonymous class.

Comment: You will need to declare the JTable in a member variable. Just update the model rather than recreating the table every time.